# getting data from Database and displaying it in List view

Tags: android, arrays, listview, azure-sql-database

I am trying to display data from my sql table which is on the cloud and show it in a listview form. I am running into an incompatible type when i access the data from my `getdata.java` class. I have created a `StorageClass.java` to add the data into a static array but i am finding it difficult to display it.

My `Getdata` class:

```
public class GetValence extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<Map<String, String>>> {
Connection connect;
String ConnectionResult = "";
Boolean isSuccess = false;

public List<Map<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {

    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
    data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    try
    {
        ConnectionHelper conStr=new ConnectionHelper();
        connect =conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
        if (connect == null)
        {
            ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access!";
        }
        else
        {
            // Change below query according to your own database.
            String query = "select * from cc_valence";
            Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()){
                Map<String,String> datanum=new HashMap<String,String>();
                datanum.put("NAME",rs.getString("VALENCE_NAME"));

                datanum.put("PRICE",rs.getString("VALENCE_UNIT_PRICE"));

                datanum.put("RANGE",rs.getString("VALENCE_RANGE"));

                datanum.put("SUPPLIER",rs.getString("VALENCE_SUPPLIER"));

                datanum.put("SIZE",rs.getString("VALENCE_SIZE"));
                data.add(datanum);
            }


            ConnectionResult = " successful";
            isSuccess=true;
            connect.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSuccess = false;
        ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
    }

    return data;
}
public void onPostExecute(Map<String, String> result) {
    StorageClass.setArrayData(result);
}
```

here is my `Storageclass` :

```
public class StorageClass {
private static Map<String,String> arrayData = new HashMap<>();

public static void setArrayData(Map<String,String> results){
    arrayData = results;
}

public static Map<String, String> getArrayData(){
    return arrayData;
}
```

and here is the activity where i get my error:

```
          List<Map<String,String>> MyData = null;
             StorageClass mydata =new StorageClass();
            MyData = getArrayData();
            String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","SIZE" ,"RANGE","SUPPLIER"};

            int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView , R.id.price_txtView,R.id.size_txtView};

            ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyData,R.layout.list_valence, fromwhere, viewswhere);

            list.setAdapter(ADAhere);
```

I get the error by `Mydata` with the following error:
`Required java.util.List
Found java.util.map`

Comment: where is your `getArrayData();` method?

Comment: @AbuYousuf in my storage class, second part of code in my question

Comment: But how you are calling `MyData = getArrayData();` without `storage` class object ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf it is in a storage class, my `StorageClass.java`

Comment: I think this line `MyData = getArrayData();` should be `MyData = mydata.getArrayData();` . Becauase  `getArrayData` method is from `StorageClass`

Comment: can you post your `activity` and `adapter` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `GetValence` as an inner class in your activity and the `Activity code` you mentioned in your question should be added to `onPostExecute` of your `GetValence`. Set your `result map` directly to the adapter in `onPostExecute` Something like this:

```
    public void onPostExecute(Map<String, String> result) {
    String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","SIZE" ,"RANGE","SUPPLIER"};

            int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView , R.id.price_txtView,R.id.size_txtView};

            ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), result, R.layout.list_valence, fromwhere, viewswhere);

            list.setAdapter(ADAhere);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
    public class valance extends Fragment {
    Button get, add;
    ListView list;
    SimpleAdapter ADAhere;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Connection connect;
    String ConnectionResult = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_valance, container, false);

        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.raill);
        add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PB_Getting);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Add_valance.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //Call to async
        new GetValence().execute();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                /** To change selected state view */
                view.setSelected(true);
                HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) ADAhere.getItem(position);
                String SlectedName = (String) obj.get("NAME");
                String SlectedPrice = (String) obj.get("PRICE");
                String SlectedSize = (String) obj.get("SIZE");
                String SlectedRange = (String) obj.get("RANGE");
                String SlectedSupp = (String) obj.get("SUPPLIER");
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SlectedName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.getWindow();
                //dialog.setTitle("Confirm your Vote");
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.diaglog);

                final TextView VName = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Name);
                final TextView VRange = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Range);
                final TextView VSUPPLIER = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Supplier);
                final TextView VSIZE = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Size);
                final TextView VPrice = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Price);


                VName.setText(SlectedName);
                VRange.setText(SlectedRange);
                VSUPPLIER.setText(SlectedSupp);
                VSIZE.setText(SlectedSize);
                VPrice.setText(SlectedPrice);
                dialog.show();
                Button cancelBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
                cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    public class GetValence extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<Map<String, String>>> {
        Connection connect;
        String ConnectionResult = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        public List<Map<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {

            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
            data = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                ConnectionHelper conStr = new ConnectionHelper();
                connect = conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
                if (connect == null) {
                    ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                } else {
                    // Change below query according to your own database.
                    String query = "select * from cc_valence";
                    Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        datanum.put("NAME", rs.getString("VALENCE_NAME"));

                        datanum.put("PRICE", rs.getString("VALENCE_UNIT_PRICE"));

                        datanum.put("RANGE", rs.getString("VALENCE_RANGE"));

                        datanum.put("SUPPLIER", rs.getString("VALENCE_SUPPLIER"));

                        datanum.put("SIZE", rs.getString("VALENCE_SIZE"));
                        data.add(datanum);
                    }


                    ConnectionResult = " successful";
                    isSuccess = true;
                    connect.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
            }

            return data;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, String>> result) {
            String[] fromwhere = {"NAME", "PRICE", "SIZE", "RANGE", "SUPPLIER"};

            int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView, R.id.price_txtView, R.id.size_txtView};

            ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), result, R.layout.list_valence, fromwhere, viewswhere);

            list.setAdapter(ADAhere);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: here is my code in a google drive, my activity code doesnt work when i do it like that https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VuYEz5hDUO-AAtDZD4YBdHFF1_wF0AcZ

Comment: where you are calling `GetValence`?

Comment: In my `valence.java`

Comment: I didn't find the call to `GetValence` inside `valence.java` posted by you on drive link shared by you

Answer (score 1):

I think your `StorageClass` class variable `arrayData` is wrong type. It should be `List<Map<String,String>>` type.

```
public class StorageClass {
  private static List<Map<String,String>> arrayData = new ArrayList();

  public static void setArrayData(List<Map<String,String>> results){
      arrayData = results;
  }

  public static List<Map<String,String>> getArrayData(){
     return arrayData;
  }
}
```

Let me know it resolve your problem .

**Added:**

After you got result set `Adapter` to `ListView` again

```
public void onPostExecute(List<Map<String,String>> result) {

     if( result != null){

       String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","SIZE" ,"RANGE","SUPPLIER"};

       int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView , R.id.price_txtView,R.id.size_txtView};

       adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), result,R.layout.list_valence, fromwhere, viewswhere);

       list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: The application runs but it does not display anything

Comment: could there be a logical error in the activity where i get my error?

Comment: I am not sure how you are still running your code. Your `doInBackground` method is returning `List` but you are  receiving `Map` in `onPostExecute` . Your code shoudn't run.

Comment: I changed it from `Map` to `List<Map` in my `onPostExecute`

Comment: Could you please explain how you have successfully run your code with that error.

Comment: I have uploaded files to my Drive, you can view what i have did here - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VuYEz5hDUO-AAtDZD4YBdHFF1_wF0AcZ